# Content of shared web hosting takes few minutes to refresh

Tags: shared-hosting

I am creating some content for my client on his shared web hosting. I notice that whenever i update a page's content, it will take a few minutes to refresh and show on the browser.

E.g. I have a page, home.php with some contents:

```
<h2>Hello world</h2>
```

I change it to this and save:

```
<h2>Hi there</h2>
```

When I try to access the updated page from any browser, it will still show the old content. the new content can take anywhere between 1 to 3 mins to show up.

As this is my client's web hosting, I don't have direct access to the hosting support. If anyone here had a similar problem and managed to solve it, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the php version to 7.2 and the problem seems to have been fixed.
I read this in one of the posts here, don't have the link with me now.